Equation solving and variable manipulating issue
Another difficulty I am facing in Mathematica. I have an equation with r and P as variable. when I put value of P and then solve for r, I am getting a solution. but if I try to solve for r first and then put the value of P, it is showing undefined. I used the following code.
f[r_]:=0.8 - 0.0009375/r^6 + 0.25/r^2 - 20/r + (8/3)*P*Pi*r^2
Last[Solve[f[r] == 0 /. {Q -> 0.5, P -> 1, M -> 10}, r, Reals]]

This gives an answer. But,
rh2 = r /. Last[Solve[f[r] == 0 /. {Q -> 0.5, M -> 10}, r, Reals]];
rh2 /. P -> 1

This is undefined. Why is it happening and how to fix it?
Duplicate question here.

rh2 is a ConditionalExpression. When the condition is False, a ConditionalExpression returns Undefined (this is by design and explained in the documentation). When I run your code, the condition in the ConditionalExpression is -0.0000226505 < P < 0, so using P->1 makes the condition false.

@lericr But if I put P->1 first it is giving real solution. This should not give a solution as P<0 must hold for real solution.

Solve[f[r] == 0 /. {Q -> 0.5, M -> 10}, r, Reals] gives four different solutions (all as ConditionalExpressions. You're just looking at the last one. Why?

@lericr I need largest positive real valued solution.

Also, I'm not really sure what you mean when you say "P<0 must hold for real solution". It's not immediately obvious to me why that must be true. Maybe there is more to your problem than you're showing us. Does it have something to do with Q and M, which are superfluous to what you've given us so far.

Why do you assume that the last solution is the largest?

@lericr Here is the link for duplicate and detailed question and my notebook as well. Though my function is different, I am trying to do the same.

@DebojyotiMondal You've got symbolic Solve and numerical NSolve mixed up. The first case is one transformation from Symbol to Real and one numerical NSolve, while the second case is reversed: first symbolic Solve and then transformation from Symbol to Real.

@DebojyotiMondal What you want is a numeric sorting and you should not expect symbolic Solve to sort automatically as you wish.

So the solution is transforming all symbolic expression to numeric Real values, and then take the maximum Max.

Try Max@DeleteCases[SolveValues[f[r] == 0 /. {Q -> 0.5, M -> 10}, r, Reals] /. P -> 1, Undefined].

@wioiw But I cannot put value of P. I need to plot f'[r]/(4 \[pi]) vs P . My logic is Solving f(r)=0 gives a value of r in terms of P. Put this value in f'[r]/(4 \[pi]) and plot the expression vs P. But mathematica cannot solve the symbolic equation for f(r)=0. So, I want know if there is any way to do that.

@DebojyotiMondal I've been digging into your problem, and find a better answer, actually to some degree, if the result doesn't contain ConditionalExpression, you can trust mma to sort correctly, but ConditionalExpression means not all solution apply to a specific P value so you need to substitute it, filter out unqualified solutions and then take the last one using Last.

@DebojyotiMondal I think you should open a new post to your new question.

@wioiw Thank you for all your efforts. I have also pisted the detailed question here.
